# iOS (iPhone) clear images from application cache

Tags: iphone, ios, image-caching

I have problem with images on my iPhone when I delete it. I clear image from disk, I remove reference in XCode, I delete app from my iPhone and when I run app again the image is still there.

Any suggestion how I can completely remove image from my project?

Comment: do you want to completely remove the images from your project?

Comment: Yes, because sometimes I want to add new one and the old is still there.

Comment: I did that but the phone still show it even that it is not in my project or anywhere in my computer so I assume that phone should have some cash or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lit sounds like you are adding images to your Xcode project and copying them to the app. Then you removed them from Xcode and observe that they aren't removed from the app.

In this case, clean the project.

Xcode isn't very good at removing files from an already built app when the source file is removed from the project.